# How can I open this locked door?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

The Outbreak Update added ruins, which contain interesting or unique items hidden behind locked, DNA doors. The door itself requests a DNA sample when inspected, but I have yet to find one.

[image]

In all the cases I've found, there's another way to dig into the room and bypass the door. Are the doors simply for flavour and always possible to bypass, or is there a way to open them?

Comment: What's that thing under the ruin? Don't think I've ever stumbled upon anything like that... o.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the door. Choose the 'Submit Sample' option. To speed things up, set the priority of the door to 9. A dupe should head straight there, press its hand to the door and it opens up!

Comment: First: Build a ladder to reach the left entrance. Then do the steps written by EFH.

Answer (score 0):

It opens automatically just send a duplicant to open it.